# I cannot able to see users created in grafana using python script

Tags: python, grafana

I have used the below python script to automate user creation in grafana , i got response successfully created , but while logged in and checked under administration -> users , i cannot able to see created users using script. Am i missing anything.. appreciated the help

```
import requests
import json

# Define the Grafana API endpoint and credentials
GRAFANA_URL = 'https://kirannbobby.grafana.net/login'
GRAFANA_USER = 'kirannbobby'
GRAFANA_PASSWORD = '*******'

# Read the input file containing user information
with open('users.json') as f:
    users = json.load(f)

# Loop through the list of users and create them in Grafana
for user in users:
    # Define the request body for creating a new user
    data = {
        'name': user['name'],
        'email': user['email'],
        'login': user['login'],
        'password': user['password']
    }

    # Make a POST request to the Grafana API to create the user
    response = requests.post(
        f'{GRAFANA_URL}/api/admin/users',
        auth=(GRAFANA_USER, GRAFANA_PASSWORD),
        json=data
    )

    # Check if the user was created successfully
    if response.status_code == 200:
        print(f'Successfully created user: {user["name"]}')
    else:
        print(f'Failed to create user: {user["name"]}')

    # Validate the user's credentials by logging in
    response = requests.post(
        f'{GRAFANA_URL}/login',
        data={
            'user': user['login'],
            'email': user['email'],
            'password': user['password']
        }
    )

    # Check if the login was successful
    if response.status_code == 200:
        print(f'Successfully logged in as user: {user["name"]}')
    else:
        print(f'Failed to log in as user: {user["name"]}')
```

I want users created to be visible under administartion -> users section

Comment: Check the response returned by the API. Although the status_code is 200, the API response body contains an error related to your billing (maybe because of the free trial). 
Here is what the API throws:
`An unexpected error happened
DetailsTypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'usageBilling')`
You can just print `response.content` and it'll give back the html content. Put it in an html file and see the entire response.